# How do I highlight a gif image in a html page 

Tags: html, gif

I have a bunch of HTML pages on my PC.

These pages have .GIF images in them and some other navigational links.

The GIF images are scanned copies from a book.

I would like to highlight some portion of the GIF image in the HTML document and save it.

Is this possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't really see how this has anything to do with programming. If you have the gifs on your computer, just open them up in an image editor and copy out the bits you want.

Comment: I do not open the GIFS directly. I open the HTML page to read . Since the GIFS are scanned copies of a book. I want to highlight certain portions as I read. I am sorry if this not the right forum for this. Where should I post this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the images in a pdf file. Then with a good pdf reader you'll most likely be able to select text and highlight it.